# Android app doesn't update in play store

Tags: android, google-play

I found a problem trying to update my app on Google play store. I upload a new version and after hours it seems to be updated. The console tells me that the app is published, i check with the playstore and there is the new version. The problem is that nobody can see the update, they see the new version but it's like they already updated the app. But I'm sure they don't, because the new version is different.

What is wrong??????

Comment: Is the version code number for the new version the same or lower than the old one? I wouldn't have thought that was possible, but it would explain the behavior.

Comment: the version is 2.0.0.Before it was 1.1.0, Before that 1.0.0

Comment: Those are all version name values, not version code values,. A version name value is human-readable and can contain non-digit characters such as dots, letters etc., while a version code value must be a single integer. To determine if an APK is an update, it checks to see if its version code is numerically higher than the existing APK's version code. 
As an example, an app might have a version name of 2.7.18, while its version code would be 2070018 (using 2 zero-padded digits for the minor and 4 for the revision). Its next release might have a version name of 2.8.27 and code of 2080027.

Comment: For that matter version names, which are only really used by humans, don't have to any direct resemblance to the version codes. They could be names of animals ("lion", "tiger", "bear") or even Git hashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To summarize the comments, it appears you may have updated the version name, but not the version code. The version name value is human-readable and can contain non-digit characters such as dots, letters etc., while the version code value must be a single integer.

To determine if an APK is an update, the update system checks to see if its version code is numerically higher than the existing APK's version code. As an example, an app could have a version name of 2.7.18 and version code 2070018 (using two zero-padded digits for the minor and four for the revision). Its next release could have a version name of 2.8.27 and code 2080027.

Further, version names, which are only really used by humans, don't have to any direct resemblance to the version codes. They could be names of animals ("lion", "tiger", "bear") or even Git hashes. To distinguish between debug and release versions, my build.gradle files are usually configured to automatically add a 'dbg' or 'rls' suffix to the version name.